# Cross Tab Analysis in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

So what I'm doing creating a webpage that the user can run a Cross Tabulation analysis on selected rows and columns of a imported datafile. I'm converting the file into a pandas dataframe, and then using pandas.crosstab to process it. However, because crosstab outputs a "stacked", or multi-indexed, table, I'm having to pivot it so it's easier to use and output back to the webpage. I've been trying to use the pivot function that pandas has, but having trouble finding a good, dynamic example.

[Here's](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) some documentation of the pivoting in pandas I've been looking at, but it doesn't show an example where the column and row labels would be dynamic.

Right now my crosstab function is:

```
cross_tab = pd.crosstab([dataframe[row] for row in selected_rows], [dataframe[col] for col in selected_columns], margins=False, dropna=False)
```

And say my dataframe is...

```
+-----+------------+-------+
|id   |credit card |gender |
+-----+------------+-------+
|1    |chase       |F      |
|2    |visa        |M      |
|3    |chase       |M      |
|4    |chase       |F      |
|5    |mastercard  |M      |
|6    |visa        |M      |
|7    |mastercard  |F      |
|8    |mastercard  |M      |
|9    |mastercard  |M      |
|10   |visa        |M      |
+-----+------------+-------+
```

And if I run it with the selected rows being `['id']` and columns `['credit card', 'gender']` it would look like...

```
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
|credit_card |americanexpress |mastercard |visa   |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
|gender      | F  M           | F  M      | F  M  |
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
|id          |                |           |       |
|1           | 1  0           | 0  0      | 0  0  |
|2           | 0  0           | 0  0      | 0  1  |
|3           | 0  1           | 0  0      | 0  0  |
|4           | 1  0           | 0  0      | 0  0  | 
|5           | 0  0           | 0  1      | 0  0  |  
|6           | 0  0           | 0  0      | 0  1  |   
|7           | 0  0           | 1  0      | 0  0  | 
|8           | 0  0           | 0  1      | 0  0  |   
|9           | 0  0           | 0  1      | 0  0  |  
|10          | 0  0           | 0  0      | 0  1  |  
+------------+----------------+-----------+-------+
```

I'm having trouble pivoting, or just "unstacking", the crosstab to be stored, then outputted to the webpage afterwards. I've been trying to use the `pandas.pivot` to do this, but I'm getting errors from it. I'm pretty sure it's more user error and would just like to see an example on how it can be done if the column and row names are dynamic. Could someone put together a dynamic example using pandas pivot to convert this into a pivot table? If there is another simpler way without using pandas I'd gladly look at that too.

Comment: What's the current problem? Is it the output , you're not happy with the crosstab statement you're using or something else?

Comment: I'm having trouble pivoting the crosstab to be stored, then outputted to the webpage afterwards. I've been trying to use the `pandas.pivot` to do this, but I'm getting errors from it. I'm pretty sure it's more user error and would just like to see an example on how it can be done if the column and row names are dynamic.

Comment: Did you try to `.reset_index()`

Comment: @DForsyth are you going to share those errors so someone has at least a chance of giving you some advice? Please think about an [mcve] and detailing exactly what's not working and ultimately what you're trying to do. Otherwise - all we know is "it doesn't work" and that doesn't help anyone do anything.

Comment: @user32185 I did, but what I didn't realize is to use `reset_index(inplace=True)` so it carried over, and that worked perfectly! @Jon Clements I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information for my question. I'm still learning to cover all the bases in the first go. From my point of thinking it wasn't the errors that I was trying to fix, but asking for a example of pivoting the dataframe that I could learn from. I'm pretty sure the errors were cause from me not completely knowing what I was doing. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long while I was able to figure out a way to both output the CrossTab I needed to the webpage, and store it without any errors in a pyarrow format. `.reset_index()`, as @user32185 mentioned in the comments, did help. However, if used on a MultiIndex Dataframe it would flatten it which wouldn't output the way I wanted it to.

How I handled it was by using the `dataframe.to_html()` command from pandas and store that to shoot to the html page later. `to_html()` creates a string of the table in html and preserves the exact way the CrossTab outputs. After that I moved onto store the actual dataframe for mater calculations.

Starting off, I would check if the CrossTab was MultiIndex or not, and if it was, I would strip off the column and index heading and replace them with `col1, col2, col3, .. , colx` and the same with `row1, row2, row3, .. , rowx`. After that I stored the new "re-indexed" dataframe and also store the stripped headers in a json format with it. That why when I pulled the dataframe out I could rebuild the MultiIndex headings and attach them back onto the dataframe. Here's the code I used to strip just incase anyone who comes along is interested.

For the column headings, with `ct` being my CrossTab dataframe...

```
multi_index_levels = []
for i in range(len(ct.columns.levels)):
    multi_index_levels.append(ct.columns.get_level_values(i))
multi_index_level_tuples = list(zip(*multi_index_levels))
multi_index_level_names = ct.columns.names
flat_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['col%s'%i for i in range(len(ct.columns))]])
ct.columns = flat_index
```

To rebuild it I just saved `multi_index_level_tuples` and `multi_index_level_names` then use the `MultiIndex` pandas provides to piece together the headings again like so...

```
new_multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(multi_index_level_tuples, names=multi_index_level_names)
```

And finally attached the columns and index headings back like so...

```
ct.columns = new_multi_index
```

I was able to get most of my information from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), the pandas crosstab docs, and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), pandas dataframe docs. It's a bit of a complex and brute force kind of solution, but it worked for me. I hope it may be some help to someone else later on.